# Is Typescript capable of doing simple function composition?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is Typescript capable of doing simple function composition? I wrote out the following basic implementations for compose, map, and filter to test.

The types and functions are set up below and then the implementation after.

The javascript seems to be fine, but typescript is showing false positives when `compose` is used. Specifically, it seems to understand what the first function is going to return, but then it does not transfer that information to the input of the second function. Explained further below after set up.

```js
import { curry } from './curry'

type f1<a, b> = (a: a) => b
type f2_2<a, b, c> = (a: a, b: b) => c
type f2_1<a, b, c> = (a: a) => (b: b) => c
type f2<a, b, c> = f2_2<a, b, c> & f2_1<a, b, c>
type p<a> = (a: a) => boolean

//====[compose]================================
type b3 = <a, b, c>(f: f1<b, c>, g: f1<a, b>, a: a) => c
type b2 = <a, b, c>(f: f1<b, c>, g: f1<a, b>) => f1<a, c>
type b1 = <a, b, c>(f: f1<b, c>) => f2<f1<a, b>, a, c>
type b = b1 & b2 & b3

// bluebird :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
const compose: b = curry((f, g, a) => f(g(a)))

//====[filter]=================================
type fil2 = <a>(p: p<a>, xs: a[]) => a[]
type fil1 = <a>(p: p<a>) => f1<a[], a[]>
type fil = fil1 & fil2

// filter :: (a -> Boolean) -> [a] -> [a]
const filter: fil = curry((p, xs) => {
  const len = xs.length
  const r = Array()

  for (let [i, j] = [0, 0]; i < len; i++) {
    const v = xs[i]

    if (p(v)) {
      r[j++] = v
    }
  }

  return r
})

//====[mapArr]=================================
type m2 = <a, b>(f1: f1<a, b>, xs: a[]) => b[]
type m1 = <a, b>(f: f1<a, b>) => f1<a[], b[]>
type m = m2 & m1

// map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
const mapArr: m = curry((fn, xs) => {
  const len = xs.length
  const r = Array(len)

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    r[i] = fn(xs[i])
  }

  return r
})

//====[prop]===================================
type z2 = <o, k extends keyof o>(propName: k, source: o) => o[k]
type z1 = <o, k extends keyof o>(propName: k) => f1<o, o[k]>
type z = z2 & z1

// prop :: String -> a -> b
// prop :: Number -> a -> b
// prop :: Symbol -> a -> b
const prop: z = curry((propName, obj) => obj[propName])
```

When I hover over the filter function from the composition below, TS understands that it will return `data[]`; however, if I hover over the `mappArr` function, TS is showing that the input is `unknown[]` and so it throws a false positive for the `id` field. What am I doing wrong?

```js
//====[typescript test]===================================
interface data {
  relationId: string
  id: string
}

type isMine = p<data>
// isMine :: a -> Boolean
const isMine: isMine = x => x.relationId === '1'

type t = f1<data[], string[]>
const testFn: t = compose(
  // @ts-ignore
  mapArr(prop('id')),
  //=>       ^^^^^
  // error TS2345: Argument of type '"id"' is not assignable to
  // parameter of type 'never'.
  filter(isMine)
)

//====[javascript test]================================
const r = testFn([
  { id: '3', relationId: '1' },
  { id: '5', relationId: '3' },
  { id: '8', relationId: '1' },
])

test('javascript is correct', () => {
  expect(r).toEqual(['3', '8'])
})
```

Typescript's false positives get worse when I call compose with the arguments curried.

```js
const testFn: t = compose (mapArr(prop('id')))
                          (filter(isMine))
//=>                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// error TS2322: Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'f1<data[], string[]>'.
// Type 'unknown[]' provides no match for the signature '(a: data[]): string[]'.
```

//=====================================================================

@shanonjackson wanted to see the curry function. I'm almost positive that it could not be the source of any issue as the types for each of the above functions are applied to the result of the curry function as opposed to having them passed through, which seems impossible.

Again, it should not be necessary to review the following, which is just a standard implementation of `curry`:

```
function isFunction (fn) {
  return typeof fn === 'function'
}

const CURRY_SYMB = '@@curried'

function applyCurry (fn, arg) {
  if (!isFunction(fn)) {
    return fn
  }

  return fn.length > 1
    ? fn.bind(null, arg)
    : fn.call(null, arg)
}

export function curry (fn) {
  if (fn[CURRY_SYMB]) {
    return fn
  }

  function curried (...xs) {
    const args = xs.length
      ? xs
      : [undefined]

    if (args.length < fn.length) {
      return curry(Function.bind.apply(fn, [null].concat(args)))
    }

    const val =
      args.length === fn.length
        ? fn.apply(null, args)
        : args.reduce(applyCurry, fn)

    if (isFunction(val)) {
      return curry(val)
    }

    return val
  }

  Object.defineProperty(curried, CURRY_SYMB, {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: true,
  })

  return curried
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No matter how much I might wish it were otherwise, TypeScript isn't Haskell (or insert-your-favorite-typed-language-here).  Its type system  has a lot of holes, and its type inference algorithms aren't guaranteed to yield sound results.  It's [not meant to be provably correct](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) (enabling idiomatic JavaScript is more important).  To be fair to TypeScript, Haskell doesn't have subtyping, and type inference in the face of subtyping  is [more difficult](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-subtyping-make-Damas-Hindley-Milner-type-inference-so-difficult).  Anyway, the short answer here is:

- Don't try to rely on contextual typing (inferring types from function outputs)
- Try to rely on forward type inference (inferring types from function inputs)
- When type inference fails, annotate and specify types.

---

Since TypeScript isn't Haskell the first thing I'm going to do is use TypeScript naming conventions.  Also, because the implementations of `compose()` and the rest aren't the issue, I will just `declare` those functions and leave the implementation out.

Let's take a look:

```
type Predicate<A> = (a: A) => boolean;

//====[compose]===============================
declare function compose<B, C>(
  f: (x: B) => C
): (<A>(g: (a: A) => B) => (a: A) => C) & (<A>(g: (a: A) => B, a: A) => C); //altered
declare function compose<A, B, C>(f: (b: B) => C, g: (a: A) => B): (a: A) => C;
declare function compose<A, B, C>(f: (b: B) => C, g: (a: A) => B, a: A): C;

//====[filter]=================================
declare function filter<A>(p: Predicate<A>, xs: A[]): A[];
declare function filter<A>(p: Predicate<A>): (xs: A[]) => A[];

//====[mapArr]=================================
declare function mapArr<A, B>(f1: (a: A) => B): (xs: A[]) => B[];
declare function mapArr<A, B>(f1: (a: A) => B, xs: A[]): B[];

//====[prop]===================================
declare function prop<K extends keyof any>(
  propName: K
): <O extends Record<K, any>>(source: O) => O[K]; // altered
declare function prop<K extends keyof O, O>(propName: K, source: O): O[K];
```

---

Most of that is just a straight rewriting, but I'd like to draw your attention to two substantive alterations I've made.  The first overload signature to `compose()` has been changed from

```
declare function compose<A, B, C>(
  f: (x: B) => C
): ((g: (a: A) => B) => (a: A) => C) & ((g: (a: A) => B, a: A) => C);
```

to

```
declare function compose<B, C>(
  f: (x: B) => C
): (<A>(g: (a: A) => B) => (a: A) => C) & (<A>(g: (a: A) => B, a: A) => C);
```

That is, instead of `compose()` being generic in `A`, `B`, and `C`, it is only generic in `B` and `C` and returns a function generic in `A`.  I've done this because in TypeScript, inference of generic function type parameters usually happens based on the types of the passed-in arguments to a function, and not to the expected return type of the function.  Yes, there is [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) that can infer input types from required output types, but it's not as reliable as the normal "forward-in-time" inference.

What is likely to happen when you call a function generic in `A` when none of its parameters serve as inference sites for `A`?  (e.g., when it only has one parameter of type `(x: B) => C`)  The compiler will infer `unknown` ([as of TS3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown)) for `A`, and you will be unhappy later.  By deferring the generic parameter specification until the returned function is called, we have a better chance of inferring `A` the way you intend.

---

Similarly, I've changed the first overload of `prop()` from

```
declare function prop<K extends keyof O, O>(
  propName: K, 
): (source: O) => O[K];
```

to

```
declare function prop<K extends keyof any>(
  propName: K
): <O extends Record<K, any>>(source: O) => O[K];
```

This has the same issue... the call to something like `prop("id")` would cause `K` to be inferred as `"id"`, and `O` will likely be inferred as `unknown`, and then since `"id"` is not known to be part of `keyof unknown` (which is `never`), you will get an error.  This is likely what happened to cause the error you're seeing.

Anyway, I've deferred the specification of `O` to when the returned function is called.  This means I needed to reverse the generic constraints from `K extends keyof O` to `O extends Record<K, any>`... saying similar things but from opposite directions.

---

Fine, so what happens if we try your `compose()` test?

```
//====[typescript test]===================================
interface Data {
  relationId: string;
  id: string;
}
type isMine = Predicate<Data>;
const isMine: isMine = x => x.relationId === "1";

const testFnWithFaultyContextualTyping: (a: Data[]) => string[] = compose(
  mapArr(prop("id")), // error!
  filter(isMine)
);
// Argument of type '<O extends Record<"id", any>>(source: O) => O["id"]' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: unknown) => any'.
```

Oops, there's still an error there.  It's a different error, but the issue here is that by annotating your return value as `(a: Data[]) => string[]`, it has triggered some contextual typing that peters out before `prop("id")` is inferred properly.  In this case my instinct is to try not to rely on contextual typing and instead see if regular type inference works:

```
const testFn = compose(
  mapArr(prop("id")),
  filter(isMine)
); // okay
// const testFn: (a: Data[]) => string[]
```

So *that* works. The forward-in-time inference behaves as intended, and `testFn` is the type you expect it to be.

---

If we try your curried version:

```
const testFnCurriedWithFaultyContextualTyping = compose(mapArr(prop("id")))( // error!
  filter(isMine)
); 
// Argument of type '<O extends Record<"id", any>>(xs: O[]) => O["id"][]' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type '(x: unknown) => any[]'.
```

Yes, we still get an error.  This is again a problem with trying to do contextual typing... the compiler just does not really know how to infer the types for the argument to `compose()` given how you intend to call its returned function.  In this case there's no way to fix it with moving generic types around.  Inference just can't happen here.  Instead, we can fall back on explicitly specifying the generic type parameters in the `compose()` function call:

```
const testFnCurried = compose<Data[], string[]>(mapArr(prop("id")))(
  filter(isMine)
); // okay
```

That works.

---

Anyway, I hope that gives you some ideas how to proceed, despite possibly being disappointing.  Whenever I feel sad about the unsoundness and limited type inference capabilities of TypeScript, I remind myself about all its type system's [neat features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that [make up for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types), at least [in my opinion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).

Anyway, good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAJgSwMYENgQDwEEB8UAvFABToBcUuAlMYQEYD2TANhOgHYDcAULwHoBREUQDaqJgFswTAM4QAuqJWq169b0QRUrdAigAzAK6dUwZE05RJM+TgBCAGigBhfKV5QjVUgA8qBzoiQldeGl88DwBzX0pqYMIg+jJ42hTXOgAyMijSWNSqdJCoZyg0xLcabighctYsBEQtHT0DEzMLKxtpWQU8FzL3UkNfBkDK1xcC8iLKoLi5jL5tXX1oDvNLa1s+nFxBl2HRsnHSyenFhJSyiqpXPkFhUTFDZAaIOGUNH9-VFrW7VMW26bw+cDyYCo8CQaEw+3wLj8ciKYkUEWoaJWrXWRmBXWsYMakOhTThWCiGP8KMx6JSuCx-CEKjEUnQYFwcC+fx5vwBbQ2+O2UDZHK5A1KHkMAEYrsUklTkai6SUHIzVgK8Z1haLORCDpKRrLCtdVUiaQz0YFGU8WWA4EwwN9eS61PzcZsCVB7Y7sABpKAQPxYTiIORQADWEBATEM5U4IA8Xm9DrAADl0FIIFQ-eEqNgAPKB4MQUPhgBKOiYcEQ-pcXETHjkTGMcFQ2agBcqBbEfsUNTq6HBSHdQO13R9YH9xZDYcj0djnZcBY8k4zWZzLmbrfbVC7e97-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-YoHi455jVEy5Ri3ZFdMM6TaURugIC8EAA)

Comment: This is a great answer and exactly the kind of information for which I was looking as I'm trying to decide whether the pros of TS outweigh for the cons specifically for FP. I'm going to spend sometime digging in later tonight and tomorrow before following up or accepting. Thank you.

Comment: There is no good alternative anyway; Typescript isn't quickly becoming the statically typed gold standard for frontend it HAS become the gold standard. Heck even Jest converted to typescript and facebook invented Flow.

Typescript isn't haskell as jcalz said but you can get close enough to get the correct inference you need and in some places better inference because conditional types are so powerful

Comment: @jcalz So basically, move the generics to the returned functions and in general move the generics to the declaration side of the equals to allow for manually providing them where TS won't be able to infer. Okay, well you got it work and you taught me something, so it's all you buddy. I am going to push back a little on one thing said about idiomatic JS. FP patterns are completely 100% natural in JS, so the idea that TS has a priority to "enable" idiomatic JS is false. JS is a wonderful and powerful FP language; FP is more idiomatic in JS than OOP. Maybe someday the TS team will realize that.

Comment: @ShanonJackson There is a great alternative... Javascript. The answer was there all along.

Comment: "there is a great alternative to javascript with types its javascript" that's what i'm reading. You seem like a very salty individual basically out to shit all over typescript from the get-go.

Typescript noImplicitAny: false, strict: false is just Javascript with enums and namespaces. Typescript is javascript as javascript is a subset of typescript.

If you have problems with the inference which i find actually very good then make a pull request typescript is open source, or wait for it to get better which it will.

Comment: @ShanonJackson Maybe I am a bit sour on TS, but I didn't start off that way. I was very enthusiastic and spent a lot of time learning TS. I suppose I'm a bit put-off because I feel like I've been lied to. TS works well for data structures and for OOP, but it is really horrible for FP and I've had to find that out the hard way and so I am a bit salty. Especially when I see so many others making the same mistake that I did, investing all of their time and being pushed into OOP when FP is a better fit for JS. I do hope TS does get better for FP, nothing would make me happier.

Comment: I hope so too, we have a 99.98% immutable purely functional frontend (with some exceptions for impure network requests etc). Iv'e previously done a stint for 3-4 years as a Scala dev and i'm more or less happy with Typescript, it doesn't have higher kinded types or higher-kinded polymorphism but you don't need these concepts to be productive in Typescript and there are workarounds.
Typescript types will get better with how fast it's moving and innovating in the type system and i would say in the next year i wouldn't be surprised if we get those things

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to emulate a `Promise`-esque API, you can write a function that will first "lift" your initial value, and then you can chain subsequent function calls with `then`.

You just would need to curry your functions manually or use a library.

We can see that TypeScript allows for possibly infinite types on functions attached to an object. (Also, we basically just wrote a very simple monad...)

[See this compile in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGED2BbADpgZ1gB4AVAPlQG9hU7UA3BAGwFcoAuVUgGlvogALKGGIAlcgAo4XSQA8upAJSoAvJTFKuWPIRIS+9VKzAB3GAlySt3PgF9gwOCaQQQmMKiQ58RMlKY2Tm4bHV8SCmp+GCgIVhhPGiNA9kMBYVEJaVkFELUNFSSjLw8CCFQYglZmctVUOEkhEAIAOhSoJQBufiMYuISS3SJJSuqILp7UOzS6E3NLayjiitj4zybW9u6jaf47bodgbzAy1GxLNVQyHlQJVGz73OV825V1R4JFAG0AXTfKOStc5WOATY6nOAgGqwS7+B7yRT-VAAI0wmGYUAQYCR8k+3F+SMBLUh0Jg0gmR1K5WRyAA1rg6ZcvpMqKgwAhsMEAOSWXAYrk3bzgPGoACsUxm1DZHO5uExMC5qEFmGFXAAjAAGCUs6WcrhcgimTAwAAmApKqtQABZxbsft1KSdyqMampJt4hlBJDSkPS6UpJi0hCJJMD5C9JKyWtG5MrLXIWkKTqgAFSoABMUyU2cDwbA0ih0DJcheCaTBCuGdFOaMLTmFisFPB6KgLWYmAA5iMoFUal1UAB6AeoABEX1Z7L1o95GJHcZO6q10ylI8nUBHXBHcoQMDnFoXGaXP2AQA)

```js
interface Composer<T> {
    value: T,
    then<R>(f: (x: T) => R): Composer<R>,
    unwrap(): T,
}

function compose<T>(value: T): Composer<T> {
  return {
    value,
    then<R>(f: (x: T) => R) {
      const result = f(this.value);
      return compose(result);
    },
    unwrap() {
      return this.value;
    },
  };
}

//
// Example usage

const map = <T, R>(f: (x: T) => R) => (xs: T[]) => xs.map(f);
const filter = <T,>(f: (x: T) => boolean) => (xs: T[]) => xs.filter(f);

const backpack = [
  { name: 'apple', coins:  5 },
  { name: 'pear' , coins: 10 },
  { name: 'sword', coins: 45 },
];

const result =
  compose(backpack)
    .then(map(x => ({ ...x, coins: x.coins * 2 })))
    .then(filter(x => x.coins < 25))
    .unwrap();

console.log(result); // "[{ name: "apple", coins: 10 }, { "name": "pear", coins: 20 }]
```

Comment: Thank you for the interesting approach. Method chaining definitely seems to be a better fit for the language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you can even compose generic functions in 3.5.1 follow the examples here; Dont't want to steal to re-invent the wheel and write them out here.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/

unfortunately, its hard to give a reason why that would be unknown without seeing the definition of curry which is being imported, however unknown in typescript 3.5.1 when generic functions are involved is a sign that the generic couldn't be inferred

Comment: The `compose` function Typescript's 3.5 announcement that you linked is backwards and it is not curried. It's actually not a `compose` but a binary `pipe`. Seeing as it is not curried it's completely useless. It is clear that TS makes a lot of promises. My question is more about how to turn that specific promise into a usable reality.

Comment: The curry function is a non-issue here. It is a .js file specifically because there is no reasonable way to get TS to carry the types through. However, that is why the types are provided directly to the result of the curried function. If you notice each function has its curried types provided directly to the result of curry as opposed to funneling the types through. I'll add the curry file so you can see, but I'm pretty sure it is not a factor here.