# Is it possible to obtain the return type of interface Function?

Tags: typescript

I try to implement **function composition** extending `Function.prototype` with [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.2.3&ssl=46&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#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-CSlegYAAy6M8MD0PgxGeEhIBQuBByCEAA)

```
const cmp = Symbol("for composition/joint");
 
interface Function {
    [cmp]: <A, B, C>
      (g: (b: B) => C) =>
      (c: A) => C
}

type compose = <A, B, C>
  (f: (a: A) => B) =>
  (g: (b: B) => C) =>
    (c: A) => C;
const compose: compose =
  f => g =>
    c => g(f(c));

//extend Function.prototype with compose as 'cmp'
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, cmp, {
  value: function
    (this, g: (<A, B>(a: A) => B)) {
    return compose(this)(g); // compose(f)(g)
  }
});

//-------------------------------
const f = (a: number) => a * 2;
const g = (a: number) => a + 1;
const h = (a: number) => a * 5;
const s = (a: number) => a.toString();
//-------------------------------
 
const composedF1 =
     (f)[cmp](g)[cmp](h)[cmp](s);

console.log(
  composedF1(1)
); // "15"

const composedF2 =
     (f)[cmp](s)[cmp](h);
// type error expected since s & h doesn't match here
// actual behavior: no type error

console.log(
  composedF2(1)
); // 10  as illegal operation
```

The problem of the code is, obviously here,

```
interface Function {
    [cmp]: <A, B, C>
      (g: (b: B) => C) =>
      (c: A) => C
}
```

For instance, `(f)[cmp](g)`;

The type definition of the binary operation for function composition: `[cmp]` is merely described within the **RHS**:`g` scope, and never obtains the type information of **LHS**:`f` === `Function` itself, and as the result no type inference performed.

Actually, I succeeded to implement for `[map]`,

```
interface String {
    [map]: <B>
      (f: (a: string) => B) => B
}
interface Number {
    [map]: <B>
      (f: (a: number) => B) => B
} 
// ...

console.log(
  (1)
  [map](f)
  [map](s)
  [map](h) // type error properly occurs here
  [map](s)
);
```

with proper type inferences simply because the `interface Number` object directly corresponds to the type: `number`.

The hardest part is, for function composition `[cmp]` for `interface Function`, it's the structure of `(f: (a: A) => B)` in principle.

So, I have investigated [Utility Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html), especially for `ReturnType<Type>` because I need the return type of  **LHS**:`f` === `Function` itself, if it's expressed as `(f: (a: A) => B)`, `B`, also `ThisType<Type>` doesn't help.

Now, I feel impossible, but I just want to confirm. Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOJ7lW) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz in fact, YES :) your code always meet my needs, and I always truly appreciated your kindness with a through implementations. Please provide the code as answer here, and I gracefully would like to accept it!

Comment: Okay, I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) the `[cmp]` method into the global `Function` interface:

```
interface Function {
    [cmp]: <A, B, C>
      (g: (b: B) => C) =>
      (c: A) => C
}
```

you're telling the compiler that every value of the type `Function` will have that method.  But, as you mentioned, this really only works for functions of the type `(a: A) => B`.

Luckily, TypeScript supports giving methods a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters), to ensure that the method is only called on an object which matches the type of `this`.  Here's how we'd do it:

```
interface Function {
  [cmp]: <A, B, C>(
    this: (a: A) => B, 
    g: (b: B) => C
  ) => (c: A) => C
}
```

Now the compiler will only let you call `[cmp]` on a function object of type `(a: A) => B`.  Let's verify that:

```
const twoArgFn = (a: number, z: string) => a + z.length;
twoArgFn[cmp](b => b)
//^^^^^^ <-- compiler error, 
// The 'this' context of type '(a: number, z: string) => number' is not 
// assignable to method's 'this' of type '(a: number) => number'.
```

Here `twoArgFn` requires two arguments, but the `[cmp]` method will only ever pass one argument.  It would be a runtime error to call `twoArgFn[cmp](b => b)(0)` because the second `z` argument will be `undefined` and so `z.length` would be an invalid dereferencing of `undefined`.  So we are happy that the compiler warns us that `twoArgFn[cmp](b => b)` is not a valid call, and that the error is telling us that the `this` context is the problem.

Let's also verify that it works when used correctly:

```
const numToString = (a: number) => a.toFixed();
const strToBool = (a: string) => a === a.toUpperCase();

const numToBool = numToString[cmp](strToBool)
// const numToBool: (c: number) => boolean
```

That looks right, but it's hard to get IntelliSense on method calls with symbol keys.  If we temporarily change that to a string key, we can see how the compiler infers `A`, `B`, and `C`:

```
const numToBool = numToString.__cmp(strToBool)
// (property) Function.__cmp: <number, string, boolean>(
//     this: (a: number) => string, 
//     g: (b: string) => boolean
// ) => (c: number) => boolean
```

So for that call, `A` is inferred as `number` and `B` is inferred as `string`, because `numToString` itself is a value of type `(a: number) => string`.  And then `C` is inferred as `boolean` because `strToBool` is a value of type `(b: string) => boolean`.

If you try to compose two incompatible functions, you get a similar compiler error as when trying to compose anything with a two-argument function:

```
const fcs = (f)[cmp](s);
// const fcs: (c: number) => string

const composedF2 =
  fcs[cmp](h); // error!
//~~~ <-- The 'this' context of type '(c: number) => string' is not assignable 
// to method's 'this' of type '(a: number) => number'.
```

And again, let's use a temporary string method name to see what the compiler tried to do and why it produced the error it did:

```
/* (property) Function.__cmp: <number, number, number>(
      this: (a: number) => number, 
      g: (b: number) => number
   ) => (c: number) => number */
```

So here the compiler inferred `B` from the input type of `h`, so all of `A`, `B`, and `C` are `number`.  And so the problem seen by the compiler is that `this` (the value `fcs`) is wrong, since it needs to be `(a: number) => number` but is, in fact, `(a: number) => string`.

This looks good to me.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBMC2AHGBeGBlAnvARiANgBQBEAZiAE5whIgQCWU94A9AFYj1hTECUA3AChBXKAFMKpAIbAxMAGIBXMMCbgYAb0EwYAbQSIAugC4YAHgCCAGhgAhGwGEAfNp0xCUABb0IpwlNMLXlQnOxsAcz8cU1tglFCHOJc3d2BApJgHYVcAfRyDU0sbe0zktw9vX3cAmCCQsJhI92i7DMSQ1x1CNNq2wQBfYShMRDkHGkQ6OTQihudXQlI-Grr41o6upsIW2Pr2+M7U9L2hUEhYUFoIMVNxq+nXUnrwjbdgZ8Xu3gFhFhYxAAe4jAABMFMpVMwwAA6RAUEBQBEjOQAd0Ynmo9xgUggMAA5AY8YIAPI4NhiVTQkFiUhcMQABXhowow0IShUahhcIRSNGNgMNi0OgAblJ8IobjBSBDOYcKj4In5ZrYnP5jmtYsEhW4KGIoIoKGBMZNrvKILxCOEBDA-saposLVbXIN+j9SeTKdTaWAGUyJKz2ZDwLD4YjhnyYMQ8gZiILXKLxZLpRyoXKvArGkrrHZVSsMprNIddfrDXbTenzZbrbbLiaxA6q86Bj9hGdoDAoCiQBYKOF5Ea0GqYGBFLgJDYAF6maAULhW+pSGAAahgE+h+DEYHCXiEne7vf7+iQhm29RwvEEfwAejfb+YALT3430DdUCTwig2S8sGAAFU8ch4hWeLUNwgKwCATzhoBQ4jmOn4wC0M5zhkcE4BIIE+MOCIwN+2IQAw4RgFIOAbh2IAwPAeqeCAIJ4riQGVCBkEdsi+KwaO6EUKhnEYdC2RtrAcG-iA6BQLOW6oNUphoRIGRSNCiLyPQAJiCChA-IJMAziJtggAQUlDshW7yagKBoApiIAKqIMyDg4vWLZacJIB6QZaAuWJEnhNC0ZIIQOmufp+AXrahDcsywzBIGnK+fkSCFLJCHGeENh4AQYhSGAqp4SkFbLDJvHcfUKVfraKRbEh4koWewWZWAeEZN0hXwRk6UblleHOaOunBX4PRJW1dWdd+j5jeNE2TVN42CFpTyDjUg0LjAABUMAAEynOA7YvAtLVcaZK4AIxbecMAYntw5FaZa0AKyne2uKXUtayWaJ1VbhpQh-NNv1-TNs3bRcExTCC8hHagCykLwR5GFWsMnp4MMGCe5pCIDkAZeuIDhIQri1qD4OEEdF7Vj+xBHbdxCtkDUrAE97jQwjAU-DWtOkPT-X7XJJUfeENNnQT1xg+tkM6BzEBxQYhBI-wNo-u+lAAIQ6N+AB+GsPk+-6AcBoHiECMAsdB7EDddvPeZhuJgDhOKEcRpFyHhiKUdRtH0fievG2xeIca19RJXi-GXmt4V+iymDRTKUJSwl5hJTYCdXfBOUpDo+XScnB0B0VX5p5mzTc8VaxJZ0TVm-7JdFatLDZEAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extremely comprehensive answer as always. Regarding the composition type, perhaps, it should be an independent Q of this, but I feel `type compose = <A, B, C>
  (f: (a: A) => B) =>
  (g: (b: B) => C) =>
    (c: A) => C;` or `[cmp]: <A, B, C>(
    this: (a: A) => B, 
    g: (b: B) => C
  ) => (c: A) => C` is not robust somehow. In fact, I've read your another answer concerning the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453313/10598032 So, is it possible to improve the composition type here? or it does not matter even it's modified? thanks.